# Fetch request from ReactJS to flask api being rejected due to CORS policy

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I'm trying to pull of a fetch request from my front-end (ReactJS Project) to my flask api endpoint. But whenever I try to do so, this weird error comes up

```
Access to fetch at 'https://2483-103-79-250-41.ngrok-free.app/check' (redirected from 'http://2483-103-79-250-41.ngrok-free.app/check') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have my origin specified in the api as well (Current origin -> http://localhost:3000)
Below is my flask api code

```
from flask import Flask, request
import utils
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins="http://localhost:3000")

@app.route("/create_user", methods=["POST"])
def sign_up():
    body = request.get_json()
    res = utils.sign_up_user(
        user_name=body['user_name'],
        user_password= body['user_password'],
        user_email= body['user_email']
    )
    return res

@app.route("/login_user", methods=["POST"])
def log_in():
    body = request.get_json()
    res = utils.log_in_user(
        user_name=body['user_name'],
        user_password=body['user_password'],
        user_email=body['user_email']
    )
    return res

@app.route("/check", methods=["GET"])
def check():
    return {
        "status":"ok"
    }

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and below is the function where I try to do the fetch request

```
const checkApi = async (fetchUri) => {
        try {
            let uri = `${fetchUri}/check`
            const rawRes = await fetch(uri)
            const res = await rawRes.json()
            if (res.status == "ok") {
                localStorage.setItem("@uri", String(fetchUri))
                setUri(fetchUri)
                if(user.exists){
                    navigate("/app")
                }else{
                    navigate("/login")
                }
                return
            }
            clearBadUri()
        } catch (error) {
            clearBadUri()
        }
    }
```

I tried to use the function to do a fetch request to check if the api is working. But no matter what type of request I do, it gives me the CORS error, I even set the CORS origin as my current react origin.
I would like to know how to avoid this error and what it means.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this error, you need to allow cross-origin requests on your server. In your Flask code, you are already using the Flask-CORS extension to allow requests from "http://localhost:3000". However, you might need to specify the HTTP methods allowed for CORS requests.
modify

```
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins="http://localhost:3000", supports_credentials=True, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'])
```

The supports_credentials=True argument is used to allow cookies to be sent with cross-origin requests.

Comment: welp, sadly the error still isn't gone. Basically the same error

Answer (score 1):

What is the URL in the browser? In case that is `https://2483-103-79-250-41.ngrok-free.app`:

Instead of `CORS(app, origins="http://localhost:3000")` you have to put

```
CORS(app, origins="https://2483-103-79-250-41.ngrok-free.app")
```

Comment: well the ngrok url is to host the flask app online. So in the origins we have to put that url or the url from which the request is coming from (i.e. localhost:3000)?

Comment: the url to put is the url of the browser where the frontend is opened from

Answer (score 1):

My setup -> I had a react js project as my frontend being hosted on my pc. Then I had a flask server running on my pc but being port forwarded using ngrok, and I was trying to use the uri ngrok gave me in react js project to access my flask server.

My problem -> An error occurred named "CORS not allowing requests" and it was because the server wasn't configured properly to allow CORS i suppose? I'm not a master at this but after a lot of headache chat GPT got me an answer that worked for me.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import utils
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:3000"}}) #Add your url of project here

@app.route("/create_user", methods=["POST"])
@cross_origin() #add this before every endpoint
def sign_up():
    body = request.get_json()
    res = utils.sign_up_user(
        user_name=body['user_name'],
        user_password= body['user_password'],
        user_email= body['user_email']
    )
    return res

@app.route("/login_user", methods=["POST"])
@cross_origin()
def log_in():
    body = request.get_json()
    res = utils.log_in_user(
        user_name=body['user_name'],
        user_password=body['user_password'],
        user_email=body['user_email']
    )
    return res

@app.route("/check", methods=["GET"])
@cross_origin()
def check():
    return {
        "status":"ok"
    }

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This worked for me, hope it helps someone else as well.